# Why my text makes an automatic paragraph?

Tags: html, css, text

I was trying to put text in front of an image and what happened is that the text makes an paragraph without my order.

The code in HTML i'm using is:

```
    <div id="userminidata">
    <div id="userminiinfo"><img id="userminipic" src="images/minipic.png">   
    <span>(User name)</span> <span class="separadorverde">|</span>  <span>Definições de Conta</span>  <span class="separadorverde">|</span>  <span>Sair</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS code:

```
#userminidata{
    float:right;
    margin: center;
    height: 50px;
    width: 250px;
    margin-top: 13px;

}

#userminipic {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

#userminiinfo {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #8b8b8b;
    font-style:normal;

}

.separadorverde{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #93b55a;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

At least the screenshot of what is happening: http://www.imgftw.net/img/692260808.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Width of #userminidata is only 250px and that isn't enought.

Try

```
#userminidata 
{
  width:300px; /*or more*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that I understand your question - but I think your source order is wrong. If you want the text to appear before the image, the image shouldn't be the first item in the `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

The picture looks like the normal behavior of your html and css. I don't see something like a paragraph anywhere.